# Client side deserialise into array serialised dictionary<string,string> data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is serialised with `JavaScriptSerializer` from C#.

On the client side I have:

```
"{"dd049eda-e289-4ca2-8841-4908f94d5b65":"2","ab969ac2-320e-42e1-b759-038eb7f57178":"5"}"
```

How can I deserialise it so I can have a key-value pair array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers support JSON.parse().

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

Comment: I tried it but at first it didn't work. Now it's ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That will parse into an object with GUID keys.

To enumerate them, you can use:

```
var jsonString = '{"dd049eda-e289-4ca2-8841-4908f94d5b65":"2","ab969ac2-320e-42e1-b759-038eb7f57178":"5"}';
var map = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var keys = Object.keys(map);
for (var i =0; i < keys.length; i++)
{
    var key = keys[i];
    console.log(key, '=', map[key]);
}
```

This will output:

```
dd049eda-e289-4ca2-8841-4908f94d5b65 = 2
ab969ac2-320e-42e1-b759-038eb7f57178 = 5
```